# Real difference between Wifi-Direct and Miracast

Tags: network-programming, wifi-direct

those protocol is made by Wifi Alliance. After I google and research, I still cannot clearly separate concept between those two terms : `Miracast` and `Wifi-Direct`. And as I know, on StackOverFlow site still not have tag `Miracast` but `Wifi-Direct`. So, what does the real difference between those, or they just difference in business name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are different things. Using WIFI DIRECT we can send images, files or different data   between devices ( as we did in bluetooth) with fast speed and wide range.
 while Miracast is used to share our screen to the WIFI Displays i.e. from our device screen to lagre WIFI enabled TV screens. Miracast is also using the WIFI Direct technology for making connection between device and the Displays.